# Sending/Receiving Multiple Message over TCP in Python

Tags: python, tcp, communication, send

I want to send/receive messages multiple TCP messages between the server and the client. For Example:

Server:

```
ip=""
port=8888
buffersize=1024


s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((myIP, myPort))
s.listen(1)
(cl, adress) = s.accept()


cl.send("hi!".encoded())

msg=cl.recv(bufferSize).decode()
msg=msg[0]
print(" Received message is '{}'".format(msg))
```

Client:

```
ip=""
port=8888
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(ip,port)


msg=s.recv(1024).decode()
print(" {} ".format(msg))

#sending to server
s.send("OK!".encode())
```

They can communicate with each other.
I want to send a second message and I want to receive second message in a loop.

Comment: What prevents you from writing a receive loop server side?

Comment: Actually there is no thing. I mean, I can use send and recv codes inside a loop. till one time. But, i don't know how i can send second different message to server or client.

Comment: TCP is a byte stream, although you may often/sometimes happen to receive the same chunks you send this isn’t in any way guaranteed. You need to add a way of distinguising the start/end of each message. For classic TCP protocols like http and ftp (among others) this is done by make the messages printable characters and using carriage-return/linefeed the end of message. At the receiving end you have to buffer received characters until you see the \n then process the message conserving any extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code demonstrating this. Writeup is here: https://aknirala.github.io/maintaining/python3TCP.html
Code is here: https://github.com/aknirala/python3TCP

I found that people (heart-less-ly) deleted the previous link I posted (which was: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) saying that: if link changes then answer will become invalid. But I don't get why the need to delete, as after that, there was no answer!!. Leaving a comment to explain stuff would have been fine. Anyways here is the code (server wants to do 1000 tasks 10 times each.

Server side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import socket    #For TCP communication.
import types     #For types.SimpleNamespace
import selectors #For selectors.DefaultSelector()

import time
import random


# In[ ]:


totalTasks = 1000
repAllTasks = 10
d = {}
for i in range(totalTasks):
    d[i] = 0
msgStart = "crrrazy_msg_START"
msgEnd = "crrrazy_msg_END" #Hoping that this will not be in the message.
verbose = False
#Instead of having start and end tokens, a better way is to have headers which will 
#have size of the message.


# In[ ]:


sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()


# In[ ]:


def accept_wrapper(sock):
    '''
    This function will accept the new clients, and will register them.
    '''
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("\n\n accepted connection from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)   #If we want multiple clients we need to do this.
    #Below we are assigning three things to each clinet connection, if we want more details
    #like, when was the last time clinet communicated we need to pass one more argument here
    # and later, ensure that it gets updated.
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb="", outb=b"")
    #Above notice that inb is not binary. This is becasue our code will be simpler
    #if we'll keep it string (as a single message will be recieved over multiple
    #iterations). But we need to convert it from binary stream before appending it there.
    #In server we have made a loop and are senidng data till all is send, so outb can
    #be removed, as it is never used.
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


# In[ ]:


host, port = "<<<ENTER YOUR MACHINE IP>>>", 65432#sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]) #TODO: Chnage to your machine IP
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print("listening on", (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)


# In[ ]:


underProcess = {}
for i in range(totalTasks):
    underProcess[i] = 0
ctr = 0
lastRetCtr = 0
def getNextTask(tD):
    '''
    tD is a dictionary which has, key values of taskID and units which has been completed.
    This function will update the d, accordingly and will then return the next taskID to be done
    if tD is None, we are just checking what is the next value to be returned, so no actual 
    changes are made to any variable.
    '''
    global d
    global underProcess
    global repAllTasks
    global ctr
    global lastRetCtr
    #print('Got tD as: ',tD)
    #Updating the task dictionary d, and also removing that from underProcess
    if tD is not None:
        for k in tD:
            underProcess[k] -= 1
            d[k] += tD[k]
            lastRetCtr += 1
            ctr = lastRetCtr
    for k in d:
        if d[k] + underProcess[k] < repAllTasks:
            if tD is not None:
                underProcess[k] += 1
            return k
    for k in underProcess:
        if underProcess[k] > 0:
            #print('k:',k,'underProcess[k]: ',underProcess[k], ' ctr: ',ctr, 'lastRetCtr: ',lastRetCtr)
            if tD is not None:
                ctr += 1
            if ctr - lastRetCtr > 10: #This is just a simple mechanism to resend stuff
                #               when some unprocess task has not been done.
                #               If till 10 iterations no client returns then it will 
                #               resend the task (not an ideal mechanism)
                if ctr - lastRetCtr > 15:
                    ctr = lastRetCtr
                print('Returning: ',k)
                return k
            else:
                if tD is not None:
                    time.sleep(1)
                return -2
    return -1



# In[ ]:


tmpGlobalMsg = ""  #These two are defined global coz I don't know how to work with
tmpGlobalTD = None #exec with local variables. :-( Let me know how to get rid of them
ctr = 0
def service_connection(key, mask):
    #print('In service_connection')
    global d        
    global msgStart
    global msgEnd
    global tmpGlobalMsg
    global tmpGlobalTD
    global ctr
    global verbose
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ: 
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  
        if recv_data:
            data.inb += recv_data.decode()
            eI = data.inb.find(msgEnd)  #Is the end str found? If so we have recievd entire message
            if eI >= 0:
                sI = data.inb.find(msgStart)
                if sI < 0 or sI > eI: #Ideally throw an exception here.
                    sI = 0
                else:
                    sI += len(msgStart)
                msg = data.inb[sI:eI]
                data.inb = data.inb[eI + len(msgEnd):]
                tmpGlobalTD = None
                msg = 'tmpGlobalTD = '+msg
                exec(msg,  locals(), globals())
                #Below, we update, how much unit of task has been done by client
                nJob = getNextTask(tmpGlobalTD)
                print('From : ',sock.getpeername(), 'nJob is: ', nJob)
                toSend = msgStart + str(nJob) + msgEnd
                toSend = str.encode(toSend)  #We need to encode it befre sending
                while len(toSend) > 0:
                    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
                        sent = sock.send(toSend)
                        toSend = toSend[sent:]
                        if verbose:
                            print('Sent: ',sent)
                    else:   #Not needed could be removed.
                        print('Not ready to send!!!! THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN (But who knows!!)')
                        time.sleep(0.0001)
        else:  #This will be true when client will close connection. We can even set
            print("\n\n closing connection to", data.addr)    # a timer here.
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    else:
        if verbose:
            time.sleep(0.2) #So that output is not flooded
            print('Not read ready !!!!', end=" ") #Thre are clients which have registerd
        #                            But no one has sent anything for the server to read.


# In[ ]:


while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    if verbose:
        sleepT = 1 - len(events)*0.1
        if sleepT <= 0:
            sleepT = 0.01
        time.sleep(sleepT)
        print('NUmber of clinets is: ',len(events))
    for key, mask in events:
        if key.data is None:
            accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
        else:
            service_connection(key, mask)
    nT = getNextTask(None)
    if nT < 0:
        if nT == -2:
            print('Status: ',underProcess)
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        print('All done.underProcess ', underProcess)
        for key, mask in events:
            data = key.data
            sock = key.fileobj
            print("\n\n closing connection to", data.addr)    # a timer here.
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        break
```

Client side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import socket
import selectors
import types
import time
import random
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

msgStart = "crrrazy_msg_START"
msgEnd = "crrrazy_msg_END"
verbose = False


# In[ ]:


def start_connections(host, port):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    print("\n\nstarting connection to", server_addr)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setblocking(False)
    sock.connect_ex(server_addr)    #connect_ex() is used instead of connect() since connect() would immediately raise a BlockingIOError exception. connect_ex() initially returns an error indicator, errno.EINPROGRESS, instead of raising an exception while the connection is in progress.
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(
        #connid=connid,  #In case multiple connections are made from same machine
        #                  we can assign an ID to them.
        #Other fields, if other protocols like fixed message lengths etc needs to be
        #used then more variables could be added here to keep track of those.
        inb="", #Not a binary stream as it will be easier to handle str
    )
    sel.register(sock, events, data=data)


# In[ ]:


tempTaskID = None
def sendRecv(sel, tS = {}, recv = True, disconnect = False):
    '''
    This function is written in such a way that one can send a message to server 
    and server will send a return message and the function will return that. 

    Since the function may wait endlessly if server does not return it, after some
    delay, we are assuming that server didn't listened, so we are resending the message.
    This is not an ideal solution, as server might get the message again and falsely 
    assume that task has been done. This can be fixed by providing unique key to each job,
    and IMHO must be done in actual code.

    sel: contains the connection to server.
    tS: dictionary to send. By default it is empty, which in our case we consider as 
        blank message.
    recv: a flag to indicate, if we are expecting a return message from server.
          In our case, this will always be True.
    disconnect: When True, this function will close the connection.
    '''
    global msgStart
    global msgEnd
    global tempTaskID
    global verbose
    waitAttempts = 0
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=1)
        if events:
            toProcess = True        #To ensure that there is only one connection
            #                         If everything goes correctly we don't need this.
            #                         and ideally code involving this shouldnot run.
            #                         Thus all code involving this could be removed,
            for key, mask in events: #Idealy we should have just one value in events.
                sock = key.fileobj
                data = key.data
                if not toProcess:
                    print('Repeated!!!!! ', key.index, ' closing it.')
                    print('THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE BEEN EXECUTED. But what can we say...')
                    sel.unregister(sock)
                    sock.close()
                    print('Disconnected extra socket.')
                    continue
                toProcess = False
                if disconnect:  #This time function hsa been called to disconnect the connection.
                    #           Please note, in case we would have been managing multiple 
                    #           connections, this would have been added to data when calling
                    #           SimpleNamespace while registering, so that we know which socket
                    #           to close.
                    sel.unregister(sock)
                    sock.close()
                    print('Disconnected')
                    return {}
                msg = msgStart + str(tS) + msgEnd
                toSend = str.encode(msg) 
                if waitAttempts <= 0:  #It'll not send again till waitAttempts becomes less
                    #                   This is added in case, server does not recieve the message
                    #                   for the first time. So after waiting for few times
                    #                   ,in our case 10 seconds, as done by sleep in each iteration
                    #                   we'll resend the message.
                    #                   In practice, this could even happen when message from server
                    #                  is lost, thus a better mechanism to detect that should be there
                    while len(toSend) > 0:
                        if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
                            sent = sock.send(toSend)
                            if verbose:
                                print('sent: ',sent, 'From: ',sock.getsockname(),' Cont: ',toSend[:sent])
                            toSend = toSend[sent:]
                        else:
                            print('Not ready to write!!. THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE HAPPENED, but what do I know..')
                            time.sleep(0.0001)
                    waitAttempts = 10  #Try again after these many iterations of outer while
                else:
                    waitAttempts -= 1
                if not recv:           #Return not expected.
                    return {}
                if verbose:
                    print('wtoR...', end=' ')#For illustration we are SoPing 
                #                        wtoR: waiting to READ.
                msg = ''
                if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
                    recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
                    if recv_data:
                        data.inb += recv_data.decode()
                    #print('Now we got:::: ',data.outb,' len: ',len(data.outb), 'and find: ',data.outb.find(msgEnd))
                else:
                    if verbose:
                        print('NotR..', end=' ')#For illustration we are SoPing 
                    #                        NotR: Not ready to READ. (Waiting for server to send message)
                    time.sleep(1)  #By giving delay here we will wait for 10 seconds for 
                    #              server to reply.
                eI = data.inb.find(msgEnd)
                if eI >= 0:
                    sI = data.inb.find(msgStart)
                    if sI < 0 or sI > eI: #Ideally throw an exception here.
                        sI = 0
                    else:
                        sI += len(msgStart)
                    msg = data.inb[sI:eI]
                    if len(msg) <= 0:
                        print('ERROR, this definitely looks like a protocol failure. Terminating connection, by returning -1')
                        #We are expecting that server must alway reply an integer eithre
                        #representing taskID or -1 to terminate.
                        return -1
                    data.inb = data.inb[eI + len(msgEnd):] #Simply removing the part
                    #        of the message we have processed. In this case, if everything
                    #        is as planned, this should always set data.inb to empty string.
                    try:
                        return int(msg)
                    except:
                        print('Integer not returned. Val return is:',msg,'. Protocol break.')
                        return -1
                else:
                    if verbose:
                        print('No end on: ',  data.inb, end='')
        else:
            print('No events!!! THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN...')
        if not sel.get_map():
            print('It\'s likely that no socket is opened OR server is not there.')
            break
    return {}


# In[ ]:


host, port = "<<ENTER YOUR SERVER IP>>", 65432#sys.argv[1:4]
start_connections(host, int(port))


# In[ ]:


d = sendRecv(sel)
while True:
    if d <0:
        if d == -2:
            print('d is: ',d)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            d = sendRecv(sel)
            continue
        sendRecv(sel, disconnect=True)
        print('Disconnected as server said target achieved',d)
        break
    tS = {}
    tS[d] = random.randint(1,2) #Random number between 1 and 2
    print('Sending: ',tS)
    d = sendRecv(sel, tS)


# In[ ]:


#sendRecv(sel, disconnect=True)


# In[ ]:
```